# antd collapse.panel not re rendering

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have this collapse panel in antd.

```
    <Collapse defaultActiveKey={[1]} onChange={onChange}>
          <Panel header="Billing Details" key="2" forceRender>
            <BillingPanel
              invoiceCycleOptions={invoiceCycleOptions}
              projectData={projectData}
              payModelOptions={payModelOptions}
              accTypeOptions={accTypeOptions}
              onDateChange={onDateChange}
              isEditMode={isEditMode}
              isPopulated={isPopulated}
              prjStartDate={prjStartDate}
            />
          </Panel>
          <Panel header="Other Details" key="3" forceRender>
            <OtherDetailsPanel
              csmOptions={csmOptions}
              projectData={projectData}
              csm={csm}
              onPrimaryCsmSelect={onPrimaryCsmSelect}
              accountantOptions={accountantOptions?.map(
                (option) => option?.name
              )}
              isEditMode={isEditMode}
              secondaryCsmoptions={secondaryCsmoptions}
              setShow={setShow}
              setDocument={setDocument}
              show={show}
              salesPersonOptions={salesPersonOptions}
              setIsValidSize={setIsValidSize}
              isValidSize={isValidSize}
              leadSourceOptions={leadSourceOptions}
              marketingChannelOptions={marketingChannelOptions}
              activeBillingOptions={activeBillingOptions}
              activeBilling={activeBilling}
              form={form}
              selectedCsm={selectedCsm}
              primaryCsm={primaryCsm}
              secondaryCsmList={secondaryCsmList}
            />
          </Panel>
        </Collapse>
```

when projectData changes, the panel with the header "Other Details" does not re render. I am getting updated projectData in this component but not in the OtherDetailsPanel component. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does the props projectData in OtherDetailsPanel updated?

Comment: yes , it updates

Comment: It updated would mean the OtherDetailsPanel rerender! You can console log at component to check.